# Independence of Random Variables for Expectation and Variance of Mean Estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Given is a sample $S = {X_1,...,X_n}$ from a target population $P$.

The sampling is done by Simple Random Sampling (random sampling without replacement); n is the sample size.

The sample mean is defined as $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

The following two theorems are given:

(1) $E[\bar{X_n}] = \mu$, with $\mu$ the population mean; that is, the estimator of the mean is unbiased

(2) $V[\bar{X_n}]$ = $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n Cov(X_i, X_j)$

**My question:**

When we calculate the variance of $\bar{X_n}$ we assume that the $X_i$ are dependent. This is how I explain it to myself: If we have a population of different-colored balls, after drawing a blue ball and not putting it back, the probability of drawing a next ball with some color has changed.

How is this dependence not reflected when we calculate $E[\bar{X_n}]$,
where it is assumed that all $X_i$ have the same expectation $E[X_i]=\mu$? That is, how do the expectations not change when the sampling is done without replacement?

Answer (score 2):

The only assumption here is that the $X_i$ are identically distributed; i.e., they are drawn from the same population.

It is important to remember that *linearity of expectation* does not require independence of the variables; e.g., $$\operatorname{E}[A+B] = \operatorname{E}[A]+\operatorname{E}[B]$$ even if $A$ and $B$ are jointly dependent random variables, provided that their individual expectations exist.

Therefore, the theorems follow even when the $X_i$ are dependent but identically distributed.  When they are independent, then the covariance is $$\operatorname{Cov}[X_i X_j] = \begin{cases} \operatorname{Var}[X_i], & i = j \\ 0, & i \ne j \end{cases}$$ but this is not assumed.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that the linearity of expectation does not require independence. So, when we do have sampling without replacement, the samples are indeed *dependent*, is that correct? And even with the linearity of E[X] where we arrive at $\frac{1}{n} \sum_i E[X_i]$, are, say E[X_1] and E[X_2] not different since the probabilities for the values of X_2 change as we have drawn X_1, or what am I conceptually getting wrong?

Comment: The samples are dependent.  But, because their *distributions* are identical, therefore their *expectations* are identical too. $${}$$  Although, the *conditional* probability function for $X_2$ when given knowledge about $X_1$ will be different from the probability function for $X_1$, notice that we are evaluating the unconditional expectation, not that under any given conditions, and the variables have identical *marginal* probability functions.